# Storing items in a map or in rows in Cassandra

Tags: performance, cassandra, cql, cql3

I need to store users lists by customer in cassandra. There are two basic approaches I see:

```
A: create table users (  // one row per user
     customer int, userId int, primary key (customer, userId),
     login text, name text, email text
   );
```

or

```
B: create table users (  // one row per customer
     customer int primary key, users map<int, text>
   );
```

where in the second approach I would store a JSON representation of the user data as "text".

I will have the following operations on the table:

- insert / update / delete single user
- read all users for a customer
- read a single user by id and customer

Here are the questions:

1) For large users lists, B is a bad idea. What order of magnitude would "large" be?

2) Would you expect B to have better performance for small users lists? What order of magnitude would "small" be?

3) What other advantages / disadvantages do you see for A or B?

(For those who need to know: I'm using scala / datastax driver / phantom to access the database.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with A, definitely.

1. Collections can have at most 64k queryable elements so that's your hard limit. And C* reads **all** the collection during queries, so you want to keep the collections as empty as possible to avoid huge read penalties.
2. I expect the performance to be of the same order of magnitude because both are sequential reads.
3. <strike>In B you will use **not** idempotent queries to update the collection.</strike> My mistake, it's a map, not a list.
4. A makes very easy to update your schema. In B you'd need to read-modify-write your records.

Stick with A.

Comment: 3. why would you say that for case B, "update users set users[?] = ? where customer = ?;" is not idempotent?

Comment: 1. Also for case B, I have tried and put 1,000,000 entries in the users map - it works. Where does the information "64k is the limit" come from?

Comment: 2. I did some measurements, and I can confirm "same order of magnitude" - for 100 users, approach B is approx 25% faster than approach A for most use cases. For 5,000 users, B is still faster for all use cases except of "read a single user", where B takes three time longer.

Comment: 1. Reference is [DataStax Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCollections.html).
2. IMHO approach B *can* be faster, unless you need to query a single user where C* will read all the collection for one user only. And that "faster" will be more and more thin as the size of the items in the collection gets bigger and bigger.
3. Ah yes, sorry my mistake, it's a map, not a list, so it is idempotent.
4. If you need to expand your users table you'll need to perform a read-modify-write cycle in B, while in A you simply issue an update.